# Safari/iOS basic authentication dialog on every page load

Tags: ios, authentication, nginx, https, safari

I have a https website running on NGINX and protected with basic authentication.

It works well except on iOS/Safari on iPhone (iOS version 9.3.1) -- Safari shows authorization dialog on every page load even after entering credentials, but still loads the page in background.

Is there any way to avoid showing auth dialog on every page load?

Part of NGINX config:

```
server {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
# ... more config
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having this issue....

Comment: No, I did not. It only affected our internal testing, not a client-facing.